# Multiple input CNN for images

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to create a network which takes n frames as one input and label it to one classifier.

[enter for my target network to understand me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37kws.jpg)

I want to build 2 networks,

First: With using Alexnet,Googlenet etc. model to do this. 
Second: Using LSTM model to do this.

By the way the n frames are sequential frames from a video frames. I guess that doesn't matter for the first model. Important for the second.

I'm very new in images deep learning world. I'm using Keras, but I don't know how can I build this network which I have to do. Especially for first one. Alexnet architecture only wants a frame for an input, but I want to give n frame for an input.

This is only one example from what I try. I choose n=5. To give n frames as an input I stack n frames as channels. When I tell you what I did, people said, "Oh my God what you are doing." I don't understand why. (The FlowNet architecture isn't using that way?) and Still I don't know how can I do this.

```
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('frame0'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('frame1'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('frame2'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1
img4 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('frame3'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1
img5 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('frame4'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1

# this is only a sample for label1. (a sample = 5 sequential frames)
a_sample_for_label1 = np.stack([img1,img2,img3,img4,img5],axis=2) # gives me 64x64x5

img1_ = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('other_frame0'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1
img2_ = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('other_frame1'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1
img3_ = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('other_frame2'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1
img4_ = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('other_frame3'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1
img5_ = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('other_frame4'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 64x64x1

# this is only a sample for label2. (a sample = 5 sequential frames)
a_sample_for_label2 = np.stack([img1_,img2_,img3_,img4_,img5_],axis=2) # gives me 64x64x5


model = alexnet(shape=(64,64,5))
model.compile(...)
model.fit(np.array[a_sample_for_label1,a_sample_for_label2],[1,2])
```

Answer (score 6):

See you have to understand that when you feed information to a neural network it learns something from it, implements it to memory (updates weights) and forgets what input it was given, which means that when you give it frames in sequence it doesn't really care in what order you give it frames, it only focuses on frames you are feeding to it right now, this is not we want when processing videos, we want it to keep a track of some history from the previous frames which establishes a link between the current frame and its predecessors, this is typically what LSTMs or RNNs do, they encode history into a NN, so what we do is that we merge traditional CNNs and LSTMs to encode frame history into our CNNs. So instead of using Alexnet and LSTM separately, use [CNN-LSTMS](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-CNN-LSTM-model-work), you may use Alexnet as a backbone for this network and it should work

Now as to why stacking channels is wrong is that you are basically confusing it with this merged info, stacking channels of the images makes it treat the N images as one and hence that is not what we want, additionally you could stack the N images vertically/horizontally, so parts from every frame are included into the input, but this just poses more work for the NN, and could lead it to not learning anything, so what you could do is that instead of feeding input to all the nodes, you make N equal partitions of these nodes and feed each stack imaged to a unique set of the nodes, so what you would be doing is that you would have a video of frames of shape 100,200,3 and lets say N is 5, so if you vertically stack images then the input shape of your NN would be 500,200,3 and you could have 1000 input nodes, so nodes 0-200 would get 0-100,200,3 pixels, frames 200-400 would get 100-200,200,3 pixels and so on. But then again you cannot ensure if your NN would learn anything.

Unless you are hell bent on not using LSTM-CNNs you may try the above approach but i dont confirm that you will get viable results, your best approach is using LSTM-CNNS

Additional information Edit:

[image: Traditional NN]

Refer to the image above it shows a traditional NN, what we do is that we feed all the nodes of our input layer to all of the nodes in the next layer, so if the input nodes were actually 5 images stacked on top of each other all images would go to all nodes, and this way the NN would have to learn to differentiate between the images, thats not what we want

[image]

What i suggest doing is illustrated in the diagram above, you stack 5 images on top of each other and instead of feeding the entire image stack to each and every input node, we divide our input nodes into partitions, so if we stack 5 images we make 5 partitions , now the nodes in partition 1 will only get the 1st image pixels, and nodes in partition 2 will only get the 2nd image pixels and so on , so if you had 1000 input nodes, first 200 would get image 1, nodes 200-400 would get image 2 , nodes 400-600 would get image 3, nodes 600-800 would get image 4 and nodes 800-1000 image 5, you may then later on interconnect the output nodes of the input layers and you could achieve a viable architecture. I hope this better illustrates my point :)

Comment: Thanks I couldn't understand after the sentence "you make N equal partitions of these nodes". Can you explain in a more explanatory way?

Comment: i have made edits to the answer using diagrams to better explain my point, please have a look :)